# How To Store the Login Date and Logout Date in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

hi there I want to store the login date and logout date for each user

for statistics purposes :

login is something so easy but what about the logout

which is the best event or something that let us know the logout 
regardless the logout button which is also so easy .

I mean how to know that session finished in asp.net mvc .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621744/how-to-handle-session-end-in-global-asax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time a new session is instantiated, you could store the session id and login date in a database along with a null logout date field. If logout is explicit, you can fill this in. On regular intervals, you can execute batches against the database to record a "logout" for any items older than your session timeout that have null logout values.

**Edit:** Just as a side note, you'd probably also need a "last activity" field to make sure you aren't recording a logout for a currently active session.

Comment: so there is nothing event Session time out like in Regular asp.net global asax ???

Comment: Can you tell me about how to excute batches on regular intervals ??

Comment: @feras: I typically use the task scheduler under the control panels. I write small windows forms controls that can run with/without interactivity that are scheduled with various command line parameters to perform these tasks. You could probably use a windows service, but I think a small console or winforms application would be most suitable.

Comment: excuse me sir but The application is in shared host not in my own server so I can only use my asp.net application . don't you think making a timer object for each session is a good idea or is it a waste of performance ,,, any other ideas ?

Comment: @feras - A timer wouldn't be a very good idea because of the overhead it would add (timers are expensive constructs), but you could also achieve a similar result if you keep a static application variable that holds a counter or last-attempted date and then use that to perform an action in the `Application_BeginRequest` method of global.asax. Here is also a link with some other ideas for similar solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/asp-netbest-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks

Comment: I read a solution about that could you tell me your opinion :http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/index.php/2008/11/23/detecting-session-timeouts-using-a-aspnet-mvc-action-filter/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code within Global.asax to detect when a session has ended (and perform some kind of action).

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform action here
}
```