# Upload a file and destory it after session is completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to upload a file through asp.net mvc and delete the file after the session is destroyed ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link which has code in c#. This will tell you how to find a file and delete it, but you must handle checking for session and associated logic. [Link](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/file/file-delfile-aspnet2-csharp.aspx)

Comment: @mahesh, did this help you, or do you need help writing the other logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Session_End in global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621744/how-to-handle-session-end-in-global-asax) however the latter is very [predictable](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Mystries_of_when_does_Session_End_event_fires_in_AspNet.aspx). If I were you I would delete the temporary files after a certain amount of time e.g. I will delete all  files which are one day old.

Answer (score 0):

if i were to do the same thing in java.. i will write a session listener and fireup deleting files on session invalidation...

check whether same kind of thing exists in ASP.NET ..