# how we configure that only 10 users access the asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

```
< system.web >

< authorization >

< allow roles = " User " />

< deny users = " * " />

</ authorization >

</ system.web >
```

In which section I write code and what I write to configure that only 10 users access the asp.net website

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in ASP.NET feature for that; you will have to write your own code.

A good starting point will be to count the number of current users in `Session_Start` and `Session_End`, but note that [you cannot reliably detect the fact that a user closed his browser without "logging out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621744/how-to-handle-session-end-in-global-asax).

---

EDIT: If you use the ASP.NET Membership provider, [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y0) can give you an *estimate* of how many users are currently using your application. It reports "*the number of users for the current [application] where the last-activity date is greater than the current time less [some configurable time window].*"

Comment: Note: Session_end just triggered in InProc mode .if you use SQL mode u just use another strategy like save IP and last activity time

Answer (score 0):

you can set maxconnection in  in machine config

Comment: but this is for all webapplicatioin

Comment: yes..it is wfor httpConnections only.You can control number of connections to IIS on the websever.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to limit number of users or number of sessions both. 
ASP.NET membership provider is good option for restricting number of users.

You can limit maximum number of session allowed in web.config.

```
<system.webServer> 
  <asp>
    <session max =""/>
  </asp>
</system.webServer>
```

Hhere is a [link](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/asp/session) that describes session configuration in IIS too.