# How to detect session expire programmatically

Tags: asp.net, session

i search google and found many answers for detecting session expiry programmatically. this is code which i saw everyone use it

```
global.asax
---------------
protected void Session_Start(object src, EventArgs e)
{
if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
{
    string sCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
    if (null != sCookieHeader && sCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
        Response.Redirect("/Session/Timeout");
}
}
```

i have few question on the above code
1) when session expire then how Context.Session will not be null?
2) what is the meaning of this line `Request.Headers["Cookie"];`

looking for good discussion. thanks

Comment: on Session_Start, Session.IsNewSession will always be true. What are you trying to accomplish because I think you're headed down the wrong path.

Comment: If you want to hook up to session end check out this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621744/how-to-handle-session-end-in-global-asax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) when session expire then how Context.Session will not be null?

Your code triggers when a user comes back to the server with an expired session.
The session object in this code is the new empty session which is beginning. 
Remember you are in Session_Start, not in Session_End.

> 2) what is the meaning of this line Request.Headers["Cookie"];

The cookie contains the session's id. If a user is requesting a ressource, providing a session id, and Session_start is triggered, that almost certainly means that the session id refers to an expired session object. A specific message is then displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Session_End` method in global.asax file

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    // Clean up session resources
}
```