# Custom Session not expiring in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, amazon-web-services, web-config

I am using custom session mode in asp.net MVC and set the timeout to 2 minutes. But after 2 minutes session is not expiring ?

```
<sessionState timeout="10" mode="Custom" customProvider="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider" cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider" type="Amazon.SessionProvider.DynamoDBSessionStateStore" Region="us-west-2" Application="--" Table="ASP.NET_SessionState" ReadCapacityUnits="3" WriteCapacityUnits="1" CreateIfNotExist="true" AWSAccessKey="--" AWSSecretKey="--" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home" timeout="10" slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: It seems like the `DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider` isn't properly handling expiration. It seems like you should open an issue on https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-session-provider or maybe you should just fork it yourself

Comment: @ChrisMarisic if i set normal asp.net session like this "<sessionState timeout="2"></sessionState>" then also session not expiring.

Comment: Have you set a break point in the global asax and verified that session end NEVER gets called? http://stackoverflow.com/a/621762/37055

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Yes, debugger is coming on global asax.

Comment: If the session_end method is called, the session is properly expired. Unless the provider is broken.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic storing session in  private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

Comment: @ChrisMarisic is authentication has to do something session ?

Comment: Authentication and session are in a very close proximeter but they are wholly separate. Generally you kill sessions when someone logs out, but individual sessions and auth tokens frequently expire and renew entirely independent of each other

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I have set the session and authentication settings as "<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2"></sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" timeout="2" slidingExpiration="false" />
    </authentication>" but my session is not expiring. Can you please tell me how can I make it to expire ?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET out of box, your analysis is wrong. Session expiration works properly. There would be thousands if not millions of users reporting session expiration was broken out of box. IIRC there's around 5 **million** .NET developers. Your problems would not be unique unless they're caused by your environment