# Ip-leave time on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web-application used only inside the organization. I want to store information about when **any** IP (not only registered users' but also unauthorized users' too) come to site and when **they left it**.

I solved this problem only partially. Storing information about starting the session is easy - just ask for **IP** and save it with some **ComeDateTime** property. I also solved it for leave-case of registered users : I wrapped the **SignOut()** with additional functionality I need.

What should I do with unauthorized users? How can I detect when some IP left the site?

Comment: Since you can't do that reliably for any users (including authenticated once who just close browser)... Here is some existing post http://stackoverflow.com/a/621790/477420 discussing it... If you define "leave" better that "they left it" one could propose some solution.

Comment: The easiest approach, would be to generate a custom header within IIS which will tell you the IP Address.  Then in your code you track every time they hit a page.  Then you would be following the user path.